# MessageBird originator handling

Tags: sms-gateway, messagebird

I am a bit confused conerning the services of the SMS Provider MessageBird; their API permits to include an "Originator", which is used as the sender of the SMS. On one hand, the documentation

https://developers.messagebird.com/

states that in some countries the originator is not used and refers to a list of country-specific information. On the other hand, this list

http://support.messagebird.com/hc/en-us/sections/202017565-Country-Info-Restrictions?page=1#articles

does not include an entry for Denmark. The specific problem is that using the same account, the originator is used for Germany, but apparently doesn't work for Denmark. Does anyone have any experience with this or any information which might be helpful? If so, I would appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The originator as you said it is going to be used as the sender of the SMS. 
But there are restrictions as you noted on the docs. For example  when you are sending messages to the US you cannot use alphanumeric originators like "Codor LLC". You need to use a numeric phone number.

If you are trying to send an SMS to Denmark from a german originator number it should work. No restrictions apply here. 
Something else can be broken. Please contact support (support@messagebird.com) and we'll help you out  (I work at MessageBird).

Comment: In fact, I had contaced them, I just didn't want to include informally given information in the vein of 'Although the documentation doesn't say so, their tech staff told me that...' leading to speculation.

Comment: I didn't realize you work at MessageBird! Thanks for your support!